# Poor surface quality when sweep interrupted

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3

I just started 3D printing a few weeks ago, so I'm still trying to get a handle on the tricks. I printed something with a flat surface and a few raised pieces (shown below). I'm pretty happy with the surface quality overall; however, in the locations where the print head came back for it's second pass the quality is worse. Is there any way to fix this? I'm assuming it's a slicer issue...

Using Ultimaker Cura 4.4 & Ender 3 Pro

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE!

Comment: Are you referring to the diagonal matt surface finish, or the light grey bands in the lower-left corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have underextrusion in these regions probably due to loss (oozing) of material during travel moves prior to printing them. Aside from small gaps in the surface sweep at the part you're talking about, I see a long slightly-diagonal light-gray line between the middle of the right and the middle of the bottom of your image, which appears to be material that oozed during combing.

Make sure you have retraction enabled, have sufficient retraction (at least 6 mm for bowden; somewhat less for direct-drive) and either disable combining or set max combing distance very small (like 1.5x nozzle width) and see if this helps.